# Implementing vector in js

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a vector in **Javascript** with the following requirements:

- Can access an item using a numeric index (position)
- Can delete an item using a numeric index (position) - even in the middle of the collection
- Can add an item to the end of the vector

What is the preferable way to do it?

Comment: Why not just use an array? They fill all your criterias there, unless you have some other ones you didn't mention

Comment: Are you sure you know what a vector is? And why there isn't one in js or more over why there IS one in java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays do this already:

```
var a = [1,2,3]
a[1]// Access at a particular index
a.splice(1, 1)// Delete one element at index 1
a.push(1)// Add 1 to the end
```

Comment: how can I delete a[1] and leave: a = [1,3] ?

Comment: `a.splice(1,1)` does exactly that--it deletes one item starting from index 1. After `a.splice(1,1)`, `a` is `[1,3]`. You can also use it to delete more than one element in a row. So `a.splice(1,2)` would delete two elements starting with index 1. `splice` modifies the array and returns the deleted elements.